# I'm having issues with my Drop Down navigation in bootstrap! How can I center the drop down?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Take a look at the drop-down menu. Do you see that it looks rather odd and not straight! How do I fix that?

I have tried float, margin, and a few other tricks, and nothing seems to fix the issues with the drop-down menu. I was told JavaScript. However, I don't want to go that route. What should I do to resolve these issues?

```css
body{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 300;

background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00f490, #00bbc9)}

h1{font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive; font-size:4.3 rem ;}

.jumbotron{background-color:rgba(0250, 235, 215, 0)}

.drop-shadow{text-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.153);}

.lead{color:white;
font: size 2.2rem;}

.btn-outline-light{border-color:white ;}

btn-outline-light:hover {background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.057) ;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="stle.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--Navigation-->
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top float-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/images/logo-dans-meat-yogurt.svg" alt="Dan's yogurt Company " width="150" height="ms-auto">
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-dark">
          <li class="nav-item btn btn-outline-light  ">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>

            <!--button Drop down-->
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown btn btn-outline-light mx-4" style = "width:120px;">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
             Flavors
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu float-start
            " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ham</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beef</a></li>

              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Chicken

              </a></li>

              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Fish

              </a></li>
            </ul>
<!--Button Normal -->

          <li class="nav-item btn btn-outline-light text-white"style = "width:120px";>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>


        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!--Jumbotrun-->
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-7 text-center text-md-left">
     <h1 class="display-3 text-white drop-shadow">Thick & Creamy</h1>
    <p class="lead">With real meat chunks !</p>

      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg mt-4 px-5 py-3 mb-5" href="#" role="button">Pricing</a></p></div>



   <div class="col-12 mt-5 col-md-5 mb-md-0"><img src ="/images/hero1.png" alt="Dan's Meat Yougurts" class="float-right img-fluid">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!--Carosel-->
<div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
        <img src="/images/yogurt-1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
        <img src="/images/yogurt-2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/images/yogurt-3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<!--Cards-->
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/product1.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div><div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="images/product2.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div><div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/product3.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mx-4` and replace it with `m-auto` for `margin: auto;`.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00f490, #00bbc9)
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
  font-size: 4.3 rem;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: rgba(0250, 235, 215, 0)
}

.drop-shadow {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.153);
}

.lead {
  color: white;
  font: size 2.2rem;
}

.btn-outline-light {
  border-color: white;
}

btn-outline-light:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.057);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stle.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Navigation-->
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top float-right">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="/images/logo-dans-meat-yogurt.svg" alt="Dan's yogurt Company " width="150" height="ms-auto">
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-dark">
            <li class="nav-item btn btn-outline-light  ">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>

              <!--button Drop down-->
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown btn btn-outline-light m-auto" style="width:120px;">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
             Flavors
            </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu float-start
            " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ham</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beef</a></li>

                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Chicken

              </a></li>

                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Fish
                
              </a></li>
              </ul>
              <!--Button Normal -->

              <li class="nav-item btn btn-outline-light text-white m-auto" style="width:120px" ;>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>


          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Jumbotrun-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 text-center text-md-left">
          <h1 class="display-3 text-white drop-shadow">Thick & Creamy</h1>
          <p class="lead">With real meat chunks !</p>

          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg mt-4 px-5 py-3 mb-5" href="#" role="button">Pricing</a></p>
        </div>



        <div class="col-12 mt-5 col-md-5 mb-md-0"><img src="/images/hero1.png" alt="Dan's Meat Yougurts" class="float-right img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Carosel-->
    <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
          <img src="/images/yogurt-1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
          <img src="/images/yogurt-2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/images/yogurt-3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/product1.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/product2.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/product3.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```